# Problems during the installation of OpenFOAM231 and Paraview410

Tags: 14.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 lts on a partition on my laptop and after installing just a few apps, I am trying to run the installation of OpenFOAM following the instruction given on their website - http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php
Until step 3 everything seems to work, but when I type `sudo apt-get install paraviewopenfoam410` I receive the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've tried everything explained in here - [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) - but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Have you had a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/588695/cant-install-libglew-dev-because-libcheese-and-libclutter-dont-have-the-requir) yet?  Could you please report back if that solution helps?

Comment: Thank you! I have solved the problem using command aptitude instead of apt-get. It gives alternatives solutions which work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem installing OpenFOAM2.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 lts
You have to update all the unmet dependencies manually.

Try this link [Installing qt4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593644/installing-qt4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

In your terminal (as the root user) type the command: apt-get install libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0

This should update all the unmet dependencies so that you can install all the required packages for OpenFOAM.

Good luck!